# NextJS | Typescript issue when i import my protected auth to page

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side, protected, high-order-component

```
this my protected.tsx,when i one use this on page below,some error comes like
```

Server Error

Error: Attempted to call the default export of C:\Importir.id\NextJs\diecast-app\app\hoc\withProtected.tsx from the server but it's on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { useUser } from '../context/user';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

interface ProtectedProps {}

const withProtected = (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<ProtectedProps>) => {
  const WithProtected: React.FC<ProtectedProps> = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const user = useUser();
    const { uid } = user;

    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }

    console.log({ uid });

    if (!uid) {
      router.replace('/');
      return <></>;
    }

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };

  return WithProtected;
};

export default withProtected;
```

and this page code  thats have error

```
import React from 'react';
import withProtected from '../hoc/withProtected';

const StorePage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Halaman diecast</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withProtected(StorePage);
```

please solve my problem,i really say thankyou for you all

Comment: It's because of the `use client` directive in the `withProtected` module. Either remove it from `withProtected` or add the `use client` directive to your page.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to an attempt to use a client-side function on the server-side in a Next.js application. The `withProtected` higher-order component (HOC) you've created is designed to work on the client-side, but Next.js tries to execute it on the server during server-side rendering (SSR), which leads to the error.

1. **Use `useEffect` for Client-Side Operations**: Since you're dealing with authentication and routing, which are inherently client-side operations, you should perform these inside a useEffect hook. This will ensure they are only executed on the client-side after the component has mounted.
2. **Return a Placeholder on the Server-Side**: During the server-side rendering, return a placeholder (like null or a loading component) until the client-side script takes over.
3. **Redirect on the Client-Side**: Perform the redirection using `useRouter` inside the `useEffect` hook.

Try this way -

`withProtected.tsx`:

```
'use client';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useUser } from '../context/user';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

interface ProtectedProps {}

const withProtected = (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<ProtectedProps>) => {
  const WithProtected: React.FC<ProtectedProps> = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const user = useUser();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!user.uid) {
        router.replace('/');
      }
    }, [user, router]);

    // Return null or a loading component on the server
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !user.uid) {
      return null;
    }

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };

  return WithProtected;
};

export default withProtected;
```

page component (`StorePage`) remains the same:

```
import React from 'react';
import withProtected from '../hoc/withProtected';

const StorePage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Halaman diecast</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withProtected(StorePage);
```

Comment: i already do this,but the problem also same

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score -1):

You are importing useRouter from the wrong package. useRouter should be taken from next/router, but according to the error message it tried to be taken from next/navigation

```html
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

Additionally, the withProtected higher-order component (HOC) cannot check the user's login status during SSR (server-side rendering), so it must be executed only on the client side.

Comment: i already to this,but the problem not finish Error: Attempted to call the default export of C:\Importir.id\NextJs\diecast-app\app\hoc\withProtected.tsx from the server but it's on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
app\Store\page.tsx (12:29) @ StorePage
  10 | };
  11 |
> 12 | export default withProtected(StorePage);
     |                             ^